# Is it possible to add a Custom Navigation in my site host without using top link bar?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server, mysites

I want to add Custom Navigation in my site host (person.aspx page) by using Structural navigation or Managed Navigation in SharePoint 2013.

Comment: Yes it is possible

Comment: If you want for specific site then customize your masterpage accordingly

Comment: If you want for any specific page then write JSOM and place it in CQWP or Script Editor Web Part

Answer (score 1):

**Before you begin**

Before you enable managed navigation, make sure that:

You enable the SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure feature on the site collection level. See Enable publishing features.

You create a term set to specify your site navigation. See Set up a new term set and Create and manage terms in a term set.

You’re a member of the Owners SharePoint group.

**Enable managed navigation for a site**

From Settings  Small Settings gear that took the place of Site Settings. , select Site settings.

On the Site Settings page, in the Look and Feel section, select Navigation.

On the Navigation Settings page, in the Global Navigation section, select Managed Navigation: The navigation items will be represented using a Managed Metadata term set.

In the Current Navigation section, select Managed Navigation: The navigation items will be represented using a Managed Metadata term set.

In the Managed Navigation: Term Set section, select the term set that you’ll use to specify your site navigation.

Select OK.

Source : https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Enable-managed-navigation-for-a-site-in-SharePoint-49a067dc-77d2-455d-9e77-250ec7cc0a6d

Comment: I followed the steps but its not working, I hope It will work only for Normal site collection in SharePoint 2013 not for the profile page within the my site host site collection @Kauser